# How do I make a table with styled rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

How would I create a table like this in css / html?

It seems like I would have to create a table for each row, and then the table would be a table filled with tables as each row...

I can't find anything on google except for rowspan and colspan but these seem to be too strict.

What should I google or look up to learn about creating tables like these?

I will fill each row with data from a database

I have tried googling how to create a styled table but everything that comes up is just a regular table with different colors.

I want to also add functionality to this by having a dropdown menu appear when clicking "message".

Would I just use a  tag, or something completely different?

Comment: _"It seems like I would have to create a table for each row,"_ - no, you don't.

Comment: Well then what would I do buddy? @Dai

Comment: _"I can't find anything on google except for `rowspan` and `colspan` but these seem to be too strict."_ - `rowspan` and `colspan` **are the way to do this** - but you need to _think differently_: instead of a single `<tr>` to represent the larger rows, you'd instead use 3 `<tr>` elements, which then contains cells that are _merged_ using `rowspan="2"` and `rowspan="3"` (depending on the column), for example, the YouTube video column's cells would all have `rowspan="3"` - while the GPA/stats cell would have `rowspan="2"` (and the Message/Save links' cell wouldn't have any `rowspan` at all).

Comment: hmm, actually, you _might_ need four `<tr>` instead of three for each user-visible-row - you'll need to experiment and play-around.

Comment: So really I just divide it into a bunch of rows and columns @Dai

Comment: My question is, each row represents a player. But for each player, there are multiple rows. Can I put a rowspan and colspan within a rowspan / colspan? @Dai

Comment: _"I just divide it into a bunch of rows and columns"_ - I don't know _exactly_ what you mean by that. I might suggest you try creating the layout in an Excel worksheet first using only Excel's Cell Merge tool (to represent rowspan).

Answer (score 0):

Like so (click "Run snippet" to visually see it):

[I used TableTag.net](https://tabletag.net/) to handle the tedious work of handling the `rowspan` for me, though:

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}


table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #595959;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    padding: 0.25em;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
th {
    background: #f0e6cc;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">F</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Joe</td>
            <td rowspan="2">HT GPA WT SAT</td>
            <td>joe@email</td>
            <td rowspan="3">(youtube goes here)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Oakland</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message / Save</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">D</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Tanner</td>
            <td rowspan="2">HT GPA WT SAT</td>
            <td>joe@email</td>
            <td rowspan="3">(youtube goes here)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Birchland</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message / Save</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">M</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Bret</td>
            <td rowspan="2">HT GPA WT SAT</td>
            <td>joe@email</td>
            <td rowspan="3">(youtube goes here)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Palmland</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message / Save</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">F</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Hormon</td>
            <td rowspan="2">HT GPA WT SAT</td>
            <td>Hormon@email</td>
            <td rowspan="3">(youtube goes here)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Pineland</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message / Save</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```